# Generating random numbers while maintaining average

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to model traffic captured every one second throughout the course of a day. I have an average traffic value for every hour and want to create a random vector to model that average traffic.

I tried the `rpois` to model three hours with averages 20,10 and 30 percent as follows:

```
r<-vector()   
lambda <- c(20,10,30)
for (i in 1:length(lambda)) {
    r <- append( r, rpois(3600,lambda[i]) ) # 3600 = number of seconds in 1 hour 
}
plot(r, col='red', type='l')
```

By examining the plot, there is a sudden change in the transition between hours, which makes the data not very realistic. My question is there a way in R to smooth the values between transitions, yet maintain the averages?

Comment: allow `lambda` to vary smoothly across the course of the day ...

Comment: @BenBolker Unfortunately I can't, It's kind of an input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would guess no - because the values orientate themself on the average values == if the average value "jumps", the random value "jump";

but of course you can "smooth" the values between the transitions manually with desired "Bridge-Average-Valuse":

```
r<-vector()   
lambda <- c(20,15,10,21,30)
for (i in 1:length(lambda)){

    if (lambda[i]%%10>0) {
        r <- append( r, rpois(100,lambda[i]) ) 
    } else {
            r <- append( r, rpois(3200,lambda[i]) )
    }
   }
plot(r, col='red', type='l')
```

Comment: Thanks! That smoothing effect was what I'm looking for.